# Use case of increased https security in JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am writing an application that should ensure secured connection between two parties (call them Client and Server).

Server should restrict which clients can connect using https. For this purpose, server will issue a certain number of certificates that will be checked when a client tries to connect. If the certificate that the client is using is not in trusted list, connection would not be established.

This certificate should be distributed using some kind of usb device. So when Client using my application tries to get something from server using https, application should read that certificate from usb device and USE IT to establish https connection. Private key should be kept secret on the device at all times.

So far I managed to create local keystores on client and server (JKS), add them to each other trusted list and use them to achieve proper connection.

My question is:  can client certificates be issued by a server and transported to clients, all together with private key required for https connection? I dont want any data or keystore to be created on the client machine, everything required for establishing https connection should be on that device. Device could have some procedures and api to help this process and ensure secrecy of private key.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What about an Proxy on USB-Dongle?

Comment: Due to device limitations, I cant make a custom proxy. But that would be a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can client certificates be issued by a server and transported to
>   clients, all together with private key required for https connection?

Technically, they can, but you're going to have to authenticate that connection by some other means if you want to make sure that private key only gets to its intended user. As far as your overall scheme is concerned, this doesn't really help. In addition by sending the private key as data to the client, they may be able to extract it one way or another.

If you can physically send a USB device, you can use a hardware cryptographic token that supports [PKCS#11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_%E2%99%AF11). Such tokens tend to have options to store a private key in a way in can't be extracted (it can only be used with the device). They tend to come in to forms: as a smart card (in which case you need a reader) or as a USB token (it looks like a memory stick, but it's not). Depending on the model, the USB token can in fact be a smart card with an embedded reader.

Java supports [PKCS#11 keystores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html), so if this token comes with a PKCS#11 driver/library, it could be used from Java.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with USB tokens, and we are probably going to use them for this purpose. I'm now waiting for the driver for this device, but it should be able support PKCS#11. Hopefully there will be some documentation with it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The normal client certificate approach to authentication doesn't work well if you don't trust the client to protect their credentials - which seems to be your scenario.

Putting the certificate on the USB device keeps it off the client machine's disk, but doesn't stop the client user from accessing it and distributing it to others. On the other hand, it reduces the risk of 3rd parties stealing the certificate from the client machine "at rest" - but only if the client protects the USB key properly. So you need to be clear about what threats you are trying to defend against, and who you trust.

The only way to make the certificate at all 'private' from the client user is to put it on some kind of tamper-resistant device, and use an approach that does not transmit the certificate to the client machine during authentication.

Compare your approach with those used for internet banking, where the customer is issued a device that can do challenge-response, using their bank card and PIN (two-factor authentication). The card details are protected from casual attack by the card's chip; but the system assumes that the client looks after their card and PIN, and reports thefts promptly (because it's their money at risk!). If the client is not motivated to look after the credentials, then this approach does not make sense.

If you just want to ensure that the client has an unsharable token, you could consider using [SecurID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID) devices, or similar, which are an off-the-shelf solution to your problem.

Comment: Client is very motivated to keep that device and all its contents secret. I want to ensure that after client leaves the computer, taking his device with him, no one can act on his behalf and make requests on the server.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use off-the-shelf solutions because this software is made for a specific device. But this information should be helpful in the future, thanks for the response